# DateTime vs. NSDate - What is more suitable for a calendar implementation?

Tags: c#, ios, calendar, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to include a small calendar implementation in my app. In general, you have two possibilities to implement this: Either working with `DateTime` or with `NSDate` (`NSCalendar`, `NSDateComponents`). This is an essential design decision.

What I've found out is that not all methods can be translated one to one from Objective-C to C# (e.g. `ordinalityOfUnit`), because there is no equivalent method in Xamarin.iOS. So you have to do a conversion again from `NSDate` to `DateTime`. Because the time should be localized wouldn't it be better using the iOS way?

How should one build a calendar application? Based on `DateTime` or on `NSDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan (now or for the future) to create a cross-platform calendar application (e.g. Windows, Android, WinPhones...) then try to use:

- .NET `DateTime` inside your shared core logic; and
- `NSDate` in your UI code (so that it's always shown to the application end users exactly like iOS settings are configured)

If you're truly certain that it will always be an iOS (or Mac) application then you might want to avoid the conversions and only use `NSDate`.